# Videoshow NPM module with ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use videoshow to convert multiple images to video, I have tried to change my code multiple times but now as you can see this is basically the same as in the module's description page. Still I am receiving the following error as stated below.

```
videoshow(images)
    .save('video.mp4')
    .on('start', function (command) {
        console.log('ffmpeg process started:', command)
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err)
    })
    .on('end', function (output) {
        console.log('Video created in:', output)
    })


Error: Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #2:0
Conversion failed!

at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Frame\Frame\server-side\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\processor.js:182:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check aspect ratio and resolution of images, if your all images or any one have different resolution and aspect ratio then it will give you error. try with all same resolution images.